# Loading data from on-premises hdfs to local SparkR

Tags: hdfs, sparkr

I'm trying to load data from an on-premises hdfs to R-Studio with SparkR.

When I do this:

```
 df_hadoop <- read.df(sqlContext, "hdfs://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/user/lam/lamr_2014_09.csv",
              source = "com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

and then this:

```
str(df_hadoop)
```

I get this:

```
Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "SparkR"] with 2 slots 
..@ env: <environment: 0x000000000xxxxxxx>  
..@ sdf:Class 'jobj' <environment: 0x000000000xxxxxx>
```

This is not however the df I'm looking for, because there are 13 fields in the csv I'm trying to load from hdfs.

I have a schema with the 13 fields of the csv, but where or how do I tell it to SparkR?

Comment: Actually it has not been solved yet. I have managed to get the first rows with Scala, but not managed to get the str() or head() to function in SparkR. It could be a memory issue, since there are 61 mil. rows. I'm also able to count the rows with PySpark and Scala, but not with nrow() in SparkR...

Answer (score 1):

If you try the following:

```
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,
                      data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),
                                 b=c(2,3,4),
                                 c=c(3,4,5)))

str(df)
```

You as well get

```
Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "SparkR"] with 2 slots
  ..@ env:<environment: 0x139235d18> 
  ..@ sdf:Class 'jobj' <environment: 0x139230e68>
```

Str() does show you the representation of df, which is a pointer instead of a data.frame. Rather just use

```
df
```

or

```
show(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! The file is very big, so it might not be a good idea to try to show it all? I tried head(), but even this runs for ever, even though in this example the phases seem to last only seconds: https://www.codementor.io/spark/tutorial/spark-r-loading-data-into-sparksql-data-frames

Comment: head() should be fast, you can try take() as wel. Or printSchema(), but this wil show you only the schema, no example data.